# Updating new database row along with meta_key and meta_value on wordpress

Tags: php, database, wordpress

I have added a new row into the user_meta table in my wordpress database and need to update this along with the meta_key and meta_value using update_user_meta

The table currently looks as follows:

[umeta_id][user_id][meta_key][meta_value][date]

I need to do something like:

```
update_user_meta($userid, 'meta_key' , 'meta_value' , 'value for date field')
```

Is this possible and if so what would be the best way to do this.

Thanks for any help anyone can offer.

Comment: This is not standard way to use this functionality, But there is other way to used this same functionality. It is possible to store multiple `meta_value`. and there is no longer need to add custom field in wordpress table. If you want know more then i can explain you.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to store multiple parameters? In this case, you need to serialize them before saving them in the user’s meta field:

```
$meta_value = array(
    'field1' => 'YOUR_FIELD1_VALUE',
    'field2' => 'YOUR_FIELD2_VALUE'
    );
$final_data = serialize( $meta_value ); 

update_user_meta( $user_id, 'YOUR_META_KEY', $final_data);
```

And if you want to get them back:

```
$user_data = get_user_meta( $user_id, 'YOUR_META_KEY', true ); 
$mydata = unserialize($user_data);

echo "<pre>";
print_r($mydata);
echo "</pre>";
```